# What is Pandas doing here that my indexes [0] and [1] refer to the same value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with these indices and values:

```
df[df.columns[0]]

1              example

2              example1

3              example2
```

When I access df[df.columns[0]][2], I get "example1". Makes sense. That's how indices work.

When I access df[df.columns[0]], however, I get "example", and I get example when I access df[df.columns[1]] as well. So for

```
df[df.columns[0]][0]

df[df.columns[0]][1]
```

I get "example".

Strangely, I can delete "row" 0, and the result is that 1 is deleted:

```
gf = df.drop(df.index[[0]])

gf



exampleDF   
2   example1

3   example2
```

But when I delete row 1, then

```
2 example1
```

is deleted, as opposed to example.

This is a bit confusing to me; are there inconsistent standards in Pandas regarding row indices, or am I missing something / made an error?

Comment: It might be helpful to see how you are getting the data into the dataframe.

Comment: Just via 'pd.read_excel("sheet.xlsx")', although I've done a lot of manipulations on it that would be too lengthy to add... Is there a certain kind of manipulation that would cause this phenomenon? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably causing pandas to switch between `.iloc` (index based) and `.loc` (label based) indexing.

All arrays in Python are 0 indexed. And I notice that indexes in your DataFrame are starting from 1. So when you run `df[df.column[0]][0]` pandas realizes that there is no index named 0, and falls back to `.iloc` which locates things by array indexing. Therefore it returns what it finds at the first location of the array, which is `'example'`.

When you run `df[df.column[0]][1]` however, pandas realizes that there is a index label 1, and uses `.loc` which returns what it finds at that label, which again happens to be `'example'`.

When you delete the first row, your DataFrame does not have index labels 0 and 1. So when you go to locate elements at those places in the way you are, it does not return `None` to you, but instead falls back on array based indexing and returns elements from the 0th and 1st places in the array.

To enforce pandas to use one of the two indexing techniques, use `.iloc` or `.loc`. `.loc` is label based, and will raise `KeyError` if you try `df[df.column[0]].loc[0]`. `.iloc` is index based and will return `'example'` when you try `df[df.column[0]].iloc[0]`.

---

Additional note

These commands are bad practice: `df[col_label].iloc[row_index]`; `df[col_label].loc[row_label]`.

Please use `df.loc[row_label, col_label]`; or `df.iloc[row_index, col_index]`; or `df.ix[row_label_or_index, col_label_or_index]`

See [Different Choices for Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) for more information.

Comment: I didn't realize this distinction. I appreciate it. If you don't mind, if I were to be checking for missing indexes (ie missing in between natural numbers) after deleting based on some criterion, is there a "best practices" I should be aware of?

Comment: There are a couple of methods that work with indexes, like `.reset_index` and `.reindex` that will either reset your index or reindex your DataFrame. But Pandas is more row oriented, so you are seldom working with row indexes. Like in your example, you wrote `df[df.columns[0]]` which shows that the first index into a `df` is a column name. This is unlike how an array, say numpy, works. If you have a 2D numpy array, `arr[0]` is always the 0th row. To get the column, you'd need `arr[:, 0]`. Also other pandas' methods first apply to a column, and need to be explicitly specified to apply to rows.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. If there is no index named 0, it raises a key error. I couldn't reproduce the behavior OP mentioned either.

Comment: OK it happens when you have mixed-type index due to the reasons you mentioned.