# How can you just get the index of an already selected row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [60]: print(row.index)
Int64Index([15], dtype='int64')
```

I already know that the row number is 15, in this example. But I don't need to know it's type or anything else. The variable which stores it would do something based on what that number is.

There was something else about pandas I was wondering about. Suppose that this only returns one row:

```
row = df[df['username'] == "unique name"]
```

Is it any less proper to use methods like loc, iloc, etc? They still work and everything, but I was curious if it would still be done this way in larger projects.. Are there preferred methods if it's just one row, as opposed to a list of rows.

Comment: If you want to access the scalar, use `row.index[0]` assuming row is a single row. For boolean indexing, see unutbu's answer to [Why use loc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38886080/2285236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
row.index[0]
```

then you will get, in your case, the integer 15.

---

Note that if you check

```
dir(pd.Int64Index)
```

You can see that it includes the list-like method `__getitem__`.