# Drop rows with non-missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with a column populated by Nan and integers. 
I identified the rows that are NOT empty (i.e. return False for notnull()):

```
df.loc[df.score.notnull()]
```

How do I remove these rows and keep the rows with missing values?

This code doesn't work:

```
df.drop(df.score.notnull()]
```

Comment: You just need df[df.score.notnull()] or if you want to keep only null, df[df.score.isnull()]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wanted in the same dataframe you could use:

```
 df = df[df.score.isnull()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.loc[df.score.isnull()]` or `df.loc[~df.score.notnull()]`.

Comment: That only identifies the null, thus flip-flopping what I have already done.

Comment: I assumed that when you said "How do I remove these rows and keep the rows with missing values?" you meant you wanted to keep the rows with null values. Please provide us with an example to show what "missing values" means to you.

Comment: Yep, that's the question. We're on the same page there. :-)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. So removing the loc syntax is what enabled me to keep only the null values in the df.

Comment: Actually, `df.loc[df.score.isnull()]` and `df.[df.score.isnull()]` do the same thing. You might have misread it or input it in wrong.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38886211/8345749