# Preferred pandas code for selecting all rows and a subset of columns

Tags: pandas

Suppose that you have a pandas `DataFrame` named `df` with columns `['a','b','c','d','e']` and you want to create a new `DataFrame` `newdf` with columns `'b'` and `'d'`.  There are two possible ways to do this:

```
newdf = df[['b','d']]
```

or

```
newdf = df.loc[:,['b','d']]
```

The first is using the indexing operator.  The second is using `.loc`.  Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc

Comment: Depending on what you do with the slices once you obtain them, you might run into a [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4909087) which might prevent you from being able to make updates depending on whether you're dealing with a view or copy.

Comment: @coldspeed I think both operations produce a copy of the data, so you won't get that warning with operations on `newdf`.  (Note - I modified the code a little to be able to reference `newdf`)

Comment: `v = df[['b']]; v['b'] = 3` throws `SettingWithCopyWarning`. The warning is raised on chained assignments, regardless of whether you have a view or copy. You don't have this issue with `loc`. That's my point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @coldspeed, it seems that `newdf = df.loc[:,['b','d']]` is preferred to avoid the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning`.