# Replacing all cells that are before a certain year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set where any date before 2001 is invalid. I want to replace every instance where the date is before 2001 with NaT.

I tried doing something like this, but it would only be for one column and it just isn't correct...

```
if df['Delivery Date'].dt.year == 2001:
     df['Delivery Date'] = np.nan
```

Comment: `df['Delivery Date']=np.where(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year<2001,np.nan,df['Delivery Date'])`

Comment: Thanks! I want to do this for the entire data frame. What would be the code for that?

Comment: `df[df['Delivery Date'].dt.year<2001].reindex(df.index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Delivery Date'].dt.year <= 2001, 'Delivery Date'] = np.nan
```

Check out [this longer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc) about `.loc`

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df['Delivery Date'].dt.year == 2001]['Delivery Date']=np.nan
```