# Using `bdate_range` with null values (NaN, NaT)

Tags: pandas

I have three columns with dates, a `Begin` column and two `End` columns. I want to use `len` of `bdate_range` to find the number of business days between `Begin` and `End`. However, using `NaT` as an argument in `bdate_range` causes it to throw an error.

#### Setup

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Begin': ['2014-06-11', '2014-08-05', '2014-09-21', '2014-09-21', '2014-09-21', '-'],
                   'End1': ['2014-06-12', '2014-08-31', 'NaT', '2014-09-30', '2014-09-28', '-'],
                    'End2': ['2014-06-14', '-', '2014-09-30', '-', '2014-09-28', '2014-12-15']})

test['Begin'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Begin'], dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce', exact=False)
test['End1'] = pd.to_datetime(test['End1'], dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce', exact=False)
test['End2'] = pd.to_datetime(test['End2'], dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce', exact=False)
```

Creates this table:

```
    Begin       End1        End2
0   2014-06-11  2014-06-12  2014-06-14
1   2014-08-05  2014-08-31  NaT
2   2014-09-21  NaT         2014-09-30
3   2014-09-21  2014-09-30  NaT
4   2014-09-21  2014-09-28  2014-09-28
5   NaT         NaT         2014-12-15
```

#### My Attempt

So, in these dataframe I tryed the `bdate_range` with `len`

```
test['bdate_range'] = [len(pd.bdate_range(x,y))for x,y in zip(test['Begin'],test['End1'])]
.
.
.
ValueError: Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT
```

`fillna` not so good...

```
test = test.fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
test['bdate_range'] = [len(pd.bdate_range(x,y))for x,y in zip(test['Begin'],test['End1'])]
.
.
.
TypeError: Cannot convert input [0 days 00:00:00] of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> to Timestamp
```

#### Desired Outcome

The ideal outcome is two more columns, in every rows two more fields:

1. Begin - End1 differences in workdays, If any value NaT result of the columns will be NaN/NaT
2. Begin - End2 differences in workdays, if any value is NaT result of these is NaT/NaN –

```
    Begin       End1        End2       Begin-End1_bdate Begin-End2_bdate
0   2014-06-11  2014-06-12  2014-06-14 1                2
1   2014-08-05  2014-08-31  NaT        18               NaN
2   2014-09-21  NaT         2014-09-30 NaN              7
3   2014-09-21  2014-09-30  NaT        7                NaN
4   2014-09-21  2014-09-28  2014-09-28 5                5
5   NaT         NaT         2014-12-15 NaN              NaN
```

Any, idea?

Comment: Is it fair to assume you should use `End2` when `End1` is missing but `End2` is not null? Also what should the answer be when either Begin is missing or both Ends are missing?

Comment: Can you please show your desired outcome for `bdate_range`?

Comment: Two more columns, in every rows two more fields:
1. Begin - End1 differences in workdays, If any value NaT result of the colums will be NaN/NaT
2. Begin - End2 differences in workdays, if any value is NaT resul of these is NaT/NaN

Comment: I update my question. A table is there on the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the function (in this case, the `len` of `bdate_range`) to only the rows where neither the `Begin` nor `End` fields are `null`. You can set the default `range` field to `null` and then slice to just those specific rows using `.loc`. Please read this longer post on [that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc).

```
### YOUR SETUP CODE
test = pd.DataFrame({'Begin': ['2014-06-11', '2014-08-05', '2014-09-21', '2014-09-21', '2014-09-21', '-'],
           'End1': ['2014-06-12', '2014-08-31', 'NaT', '2014-09-30', '2014-09-28', '-'],
            'End2': ['2014-06-14', '-', '2014-09-30', '-', '2014-09-28', '2014-12-15']})

test['Begin'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Begin'], dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce', exact=False)
test['End1'] = pd.to_datetime(test['End1'], dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce', exact=False)
test['End2'] = pd.to_datetime(test['End2'], dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce', exact=False)

## DEFAULT RANGE FIELDS TO NULL
test['Begin-End1_bdate'] = np.nan
test['Begin-End2_bdate'] = np.nan

### USE LOC TO FIND NON-NULL ROWS
test.loc[(test['Begin'].notnull()) & (test['End1'].notnull()), 'Begin-End1_bdate'] = test[(test['Begin'].notnull()) & (test['End1'].notnull())].apply(lambda row: len(pd.bdate_range(row['Begin'], row['End1'])), axis = 1)
test.loc[(test['Begin'].notnull()) & (test['End2'].notnull()), 'Begin-End2_bdate'] = test[(test['Begin'].notnull()) & (test['End2'].notnull())].apply(lambda row: len(pd.bdate_range(row['Begin'], row['End2'])), axis = 1)

test
```

Comment: Almost. :-) I want `NaN` instead of `today` date.

Comment: Not really. This is the normal days between the two dates. I want only the workdays. See my table on the end of my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It does not replicate your desired outcome. However, I think it addresses your fundamental question of using `bdate_range` in the case of having `NaT`. The question of using `bdate_range` to get a different duration to match your desired outcome is likely a separate question.