# How to add a column from one file to another using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data sets: grades.csv and rubric.csv

A sample from the grades csv is below:

```
Student ID,Question 1,Question 2,Question 3,Question 4,Question 5,Question 6
205842,6.5,6.5,9.5,5.5,3.5,9.5
280642,8.5,9.5,3.5,9.5,4,9.5
```

and the rubric csv looks like this:

```
Question,Max score
Question 1, 20
Question 2, 10
Question 3, 10
Question 4, 15
Question 5, 10
Question 6, 25
```

I want to be able to add the 'Max Score' column from the rubric csv as another column in the grades csv.

So far I have the below. I am assuming the grades.csv needs to be deconstructed or inverted for t

```
grades_df = pd.read_csv(grades)
rubric_df = pd.read_csv(rubric)
grades_dft = grades_df.T
```

Comment: how do u want it to appear? max for each question or max for each student? an example of ur expected output would help in understanding your question.

Comment: It's the maximum per question, hence why I was thinking it needs to be transposed first. My thinking is that once you have the max score by question you should be able to transpose it back.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it like this:

```py
grades_df = pd.read_csv(grades)
rubric_df = pd.read_csv(rubric)
grades_df['Max score'] = rubric_df['Max score']
print(grades_df)
```

Or if you want to be very explicit adding a new column like @jakub mention:

```
grades_df.loc[:, 'Max_score'] = rubric_df['Max score']
```

You will get this:

```py
   Student ID  Question 1  Question 2  Question 3  Question 4  Question 5  Question 6  Max score
0      205842         6.5         6.5         9.5         5.5         3.5         9.5         20
1      280642         8.5         9.5         3.5         9.5         4.0         9.5         10
```

Comment: I would suggest using `grades_df.loc[:, 'Max_score']` instead of `grades_df['Max_score']` to be more explicit.

Comment: @jakub, true, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @jakub I'm not sure I understand, how is that more explicit?

Comment: @AMC - this answer summarizes why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38886211/5666087

Comment: Thanks for your help, however this adds max score only to the first 6 rows and also to Student ID - instead of Max Score being allocated by question which is what I am after