# When to use pandas ‘loc’ for dataframe slicing

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In pandas, if i have a dataframe , i can subset it like:

```
df[df.col == some_condition]
```

Also, i can do:

```
df.loc[df.col == some_condition]
```

What is the difference between the two? The ‘loc’ approach seems more verbose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Pandas Series - Why use loc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc)

Answer (score 3):

In simple words:

There are three primary indexers for pandas. We have the indexing operator itself (the brackets []), .loc, and .iloc. Let's summarize them:

- `[]` - Primarily selects subsets of columns, but can select rows as well. Can't simultaneously select rows and columns.
- `.loc` - selects subsets of rows and columns by label only
- .`iloc` - selects subsets of rows and columns by integer location only

For more detailed explanation you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc) question