# pandas: condition of location of elements in columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements

Given a dataframe, I am trying to print out how many cells of one column with a specific value correspond to the same index of another column having other specific values.
In this instance the output should be '2' since the condition is df[z]=4 and df[x]=C and only cells 10 and 11 match this requirement.
My code does not output any result but only a warning message: :5: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
if (df[df['z']== 4].index.values) == (df[df['x']== 'C'].index.values):
:5: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

Besides fixing this issue, is there another more 'pythonish' way of doing this without a for loop?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data=[['A', 1,2 ,5, 'blue'],
        ['A', 1,5,6, 'blue'],
        ['A', 4,4,7, 'blue']
        ,['B', 6,5,4,'yellow'],
        ['B',9,9,3, 'blue'],
        ['B', 7,9,1,'yellow']
        ,['B', 2,3,1,'yellow'],
        ['B', 5,1,2,'yellow'],
        ['C',2,10,9,'green']
        ,['C', 8,2,8,'green'],
        ['C', 5,4,3,'green'],
        ['C', 8,4 ,3,'green']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z','xy', 'color'])
k=0
print((df[df['z']==4].index.values))
print(df[df['x']== 'C'].index.values)
for i in (df['z']):
    if (df[df['z']== 4].index.values) == (df[df['x']== 'C'].index.values):
        k+=1
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.loc` with the boolean condition mask of selecting the rows to locate the rows.  Then, use `shape[0]` to get the row count:

```
df.loc[(df['z']== 4) & (df['x']== 'C')].shape[0]
```

You can use with or without `.loc` for the row selection.  So, it's the same as:

```
df[(df['z']== 4) & (df['x']== 'C')].shape[0]
```

However, **it is a *good practice* to use `.loc` rather than without it.**  You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc) for further information.

Result:

```
2
```

Comment: how would it be possible to output how many times 4 shows in categories A and B without repeating this line: df.loc[(df['z']== 4) & (df['x']== 'C')].shape[0]  for every single category?

Comment: @d8a988  You can use:  `df.set_index('x').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda d: d.eq(4).sum())`.  Then, you can see under each category, the counts of 4 in all columns (except x which holds the category)

Comment: @d8a988  Or, if you want to show also for the category matching your value, you can also use:  `df.eq(4).groupby(df['x']).sum()`   Your matching value 4 is inside the `.eq()` in `.eq(4)`.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
c=df['z'].eq(4) & df['x'].eq('C')
#your condition
```

Finally:

```
count=df[c].index.size
#OR
count=len(df[c].index)
```

output:

```
print(count)
>>>2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
df[(df['z']==4) & (df['x']=='C')].shape[0]

#2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming just the number is necessary and not the filtered frame, calculating the number of True values in the Boolean Series is faster:

Calculate the conditions as Boolean Series:

```
m = df['z'].eq(4) & df['x'].eq('C')
```

Count `True` values via [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas-series-sum):

```
k = m.sum()
```

or via [`np.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy-count-nonzero):

```
k = np.count_nonzero(m)
```

`k`:

```
2
```

---

Timing Information via %timeit:

All timing excludes creation of the index as they all use the same index so the timing is similar in all cases:

```
m = df['z'].eq(4) & df['x'].eq('C')
```

[Henry Ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142567/15497888) (This Answer)

```
%timeit m.sum()
25.6 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit np.count_nonzero(m)
7 µs ± 267 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

[IoaTzimas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142333/15497888)

```
%timeit df[m].shape[0]
151 µs ± 2.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

[Anurag Dabas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142310/15497888)

```
%timeit df[m].index.size
163 µs ± 3.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit len(df[m].index)
165 µs ± 5.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

[SeaBean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142325/15497888)

```
%timeit df.loc[m].shape[0]
151 µs ± 5.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

(Without `loc` is the same as [IoaTzimas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142333/15497888))