# DataFrame filtering: .loc vs not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Can someone elaborate on the difference between using `.loc` and not in the examples below? What is the benefit of using:

1. `rslt_df = dataframe[dataframe['Percentage'] > 70]`, as opposed to
2. `rslt_df = dataframe.**loc**[dataframe['Percentage'] > 70]`

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc