# Select a column of a condition in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I think that I'm cleaning my Data in a poor way.
What I need to do is return only a column of a conditional selection of my dataset.

As example:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 99 | 42 |

I want to return Heading 2 for every Heading 1 that follow a condition.

What I'm doing is creating a temporary DataFrame:

`df = df[df['Heading 1'] > 50]`

Then I can get what I want just doing:

`df['Heading 2']`

But I can probably do it directly. I've tried something like

`df['Heading 2'].where(df['Heading 1'] > 50])`

But I dont think that that's the way - or maybe I've done something wrong.

Comment: You're doing it correctly. It's recommended to add a .loc though as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc) 

`df.loc[df['Heading 1'] > 50, 'Heading 2']`

Comment: @medium-dimensional you need .loc

Comment: Or `df[df['Heading 1'] > 50]['Heading 2']`.