# Dataframe reported by Pylint as unsubscriptable or not supporting item assignement, but working as expected

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pylint

Have a dataframe called `topmentions`. Here some data relative to it:

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 30 entries, 22 to 29
    Data columns (total 2 columns):
     #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
    ---  ------     --------------  ----- 
     0   reference  30 non-null     object
     1   freq       30 non-null     int64 
    dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
    memory usage: 720.0+ bytes
    None
                        reference  freq
    22         Giorgia Meloni|PER     4
    16      Matteo Piantedosi|PER     3
    10           Donald Trump|PER     3
    28  Gianfranco Baruchello|PER     3
    3        Tomaso Montanari|PER     3
```

Despite being a valid dataframe and despite the code below works as expected, the variable `topmentions` gets flagged by Pylint as `Value 'topmentions' is unsubscriptable`.

Here the code that gets flagged:

```py
json_string = topmentions[
    topmentions["freq"].cumsum() < topmentions["freq"].sum() / 2
].to_json(orient="records")
```

All three `topmentions` variable names in the snippet are flagged as errors. What's wrong?

PS: I know I can suppress those errors adding `# pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object`, but I'd like not to resort to such a trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code, this seems to be an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4577) with Pylint, which wrongly thinks that your dataframe *"does not support item assignment (i.e. doesn’t define **setitem** method)"*.

Rather than disabling the warning, you can use Pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) property, which is probably preferable anyway (see *Note* [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc)).

So, in the following (hopefully) reproducible example (as of the date of this answer, using Python 3.10.9, Pandas 1.5.2, Pylint 2.15.9):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col0": [1, 2], "col1": ["a", "b"]})
df = df.set_index("col0")
print(df[df["col1"] == "a"])
```

```
# Output
     col1
col0     
1       a
```

Running Pylint on the script prints out:

```
script.py:4:6: E1136: Value 'df' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)
script.py:4:9: E1136: Value 'df' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)
------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)
```

Now, if you replace `df[df["col1"] == "a"]` with `df.loc[df.loc[:, "col1"] == "a", :]` and run Pylint again, everything is fine:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

Similarly:

```py
df["col2"] = ["c", "d"]
```

Raises:

```
script.py:4:9: E1137: 'df' does not support item assignment (unsupported-assignment-operation)
```

But `df.loc[:, "col2"] = ["c", "d"]` does not.

Comment: Merci beacoup, bonne journee